# Organize XML file - FIlezilla

Tags: xml, filezilla

I have like 50 FTP servers in Filezilla. They used to be all in the root of the Site Manager. This was a problem every time i wanted to connect to one of them.

So I organized them **manually** into folders and categories. You can do this in the site manager, but i can't drag elements out of the view and the interface sucks.

So, the question is, is there a software that would allow me to *visually* organize an XML file? Create < elements >  and move the nodes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, Filezilla's interface is poor for moving sites between folders.  I found a free solution, Microsoft's [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973), which did allow me to drag and drop nodes.  This wasn't as simple as I hoped because Filezilla's nodes are named Server and Folder and I had to expand each Server node to see its Name attribute, but eventually it got the job done.

There are a bunch of other XML editors that might work better, but a lot of them cost money.  You could check this thread for some options, or just Google "XML editor": https://superuser.com/questions/319416/help-me-find-an-xml-editor

Comment: Thank you very much! XML Notepad is a good option. It really does makes it easier and it's what I requested.